# If loop to choose which value to populate in textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a textbox `Job` in `Form2`, and I have multiple textboxes in `Form1`.

Lets say in `form1` I have `Textbox1` which is `RollFromInventory`, `Textbox2` is `RollFromMachine1`, `Texbox3` is `RollFromMachine2` and so on, assume there are 4 other machines, so four other Textboxes.

When I want to populate the textbox `Job` in `Form2`, I want to write an `If` loop which should look for the textbox which has value populated in it, in `form1` (there will be only one textbox which will have a value among all the available textboxes in `form1`), i.e. either `RollFromInventory` will have a value or `RollFromMachine1` will have a value or `RollFromMachine2`..

I am unsure of the looping logic, so I cant really figure out how to go about it.

Currently the code I have written is mainly for populating concatenated values (I am not providing that code, because it will make the objective seem complicated).

Comment: I figure, code behind a button should be appropriate, I need help with the If Loop logic.

Comment: and syntax (of how to check if a textbox has a value, i.e. do I use not null or what would be the recommended approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach might be to populate the **Control Source** of your `Job` textbox in `Form2` with a [`Switch`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) statement similar to the following:

```
=Switch(
    [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromInventory] is not null, [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromInventory],
    [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromMachine1]  is not null, [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromMachine1],
    [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromMachine2]  is not null, [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromMachine2],
    [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromMachine3]  is not null, [Forms]![Form1]![RollFromMachine3]
)
```

Though, this isn't particularly pretty and reeks of bad interface design - it sounds like a set of radio buttons and a single textbox would be more appropriate for this scenario.

If you want to implement this in VBA, you could use a set of nested `If` statements or `Nz` expressions, e.g.:

```vb
Forms![PrinterWaxLabel].JOB = Nz(Nz(InvPW, FHPW), WxPW)
```

Comment: I am about to leave work now. I am gonna try this tomorrow, but I get the general idea of what you are trying to say. Not sure if I understand the radio button option very accurately, but I kind of understand what you mean. I will try it as well. Thanks again for that suggestion, it is very very helpful.

Comment: oh wait, i jumped the gun..it actually did not work. It is giving me an error

Comment: It wasnt allowing me to use Switch in the vb studio. I have no idea why.

Comment: some syntax error, I am sure Switch works (but I am an absolute newbie with vba and coding, so I have a hard time getting the syntax right). I am only good at logic :D

Comment: @NewAtSQL The `Switch` statement provided was for use in the **Control Source** (as noted in my answer), not in a VBA function. If you want to use VBA, I would suggest using either nested `If` statements or a set of nested `Nz` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code to achieve what I wanted:

```
If Len(Me.InvPW.Value & "") > 0 Then
Forms![PrinterWaxLabel].JOB = Me.InvPW.Value

Me.JOB.SetFocus

Else

If Len(Me.FHPW & "") > 0 Then

Forms![PrinterWaxLabel].JOB = Me.FHPW.Value

Me.JOB.SetFocus

Else

If Len(Me.WxPW.Value & "") > 0 Then

Forms![PrinterWaxLabel].JOB = Me.WxPW.Value

Me.JOB.SetFocus

End If

End If

End If
```